# python pandas openpyxl Values that disappear

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I would like a code that reads the data I have selected from an excel table. Then it copies the data recorded in a new excel sheet into the same excel file. And I have to use pandas because I do other operations later
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

data=pd.read_excel("site.xlsx","Feuille1", keep_default_na=False, skiprows = [0,1],usecols=[1,2,3,4]) 
print(data)

path = r"/home/alex/Documents/Python facture/site.xlsx"
book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

df_data=pd.DataFrame(data)
df_data.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'will work')

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

The following image shows my excel sheet whose data I want to copy:
[Feuille 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9gdu.png)

The first time the code is run it works but not the second time.
I'm launching the code for the first time (print data):
[First time - print data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd8Nr.png)

Here is the writing result in the excel will work sheet. Everything is going according to plan.
[Result writing excel will work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkAF0.png)

and here are the results for the second time (print data):

[the second time- print data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nchAj.png)
It can be seen that a value column is missing

Here is what my code wrote in the excel sheet will work 1:

[Result writing excel will work 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zi8Pt.png)

So I check if all my data in my excel sheet is still present and here is what it looks like
[Feuille 1 After I restarted the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUVzH.png)

I don't understand why he didn't repeat the same results for me as he did for the first time. However, all my data in Feuille 1 are still present but we can see my excel sheet 'Feuille 1' is a little bit different.

Here is my github with the excel file and my entire code:
https://github.com/Suntoryy/site

Comment: If I open my excel file manually and save after launching the code the first time. My code works for the second time but does not work the third time. I have to register manually between each code launch.

Comment: Please explain the problem in greater detail, those screenshots alone are not sufficient.

Comment: The first image corresponds to my data selected in the excel file (print data). Then the code copies these data and rewrites them into the new excel sheet (will work). Then I restart the code and the second image corresponds to the same data read in the original excel sheet (Feuille 1). However, we notice that some data is missing from the first image while my code does not modify its content.  In the excel file all my data are present as before. I don't understand why he doesn't read all the data in the excel sheet (Feuille 1) like for the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry I rephrased my problem with more detail